# Tomcat Isapi Redirect crashes different app pools

Tags: iis, redirect, tomcat

I installed the ISAPI redirect dll on an IIS to access my tomcat application via the IIS and use its SSO.

I have installed it, using the official documentation:
https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

I have used the 64 bit DLL and have disabled 32 bit Applications for the default App Pool.
The Tomcat Application is workin well.

But other Applications on the IIS show an error message: [IIS error page 500.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blHwg.jpg)
"HTTP Error 500.0 Calling GetFilterVersion on ISAPI filter isapi_redirect.dll failed".
When I change the other app pool to allow 32 bit applications, the the error disappiers.
Unfortunatly there is an application where the 32 bit applicatin must not be checked.

Comment: Microsoft only recommends HttpPlatformHandler for Java web apps on IIS, https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/